# What can happen when I forcly terminate thread at Winsock connect function?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, winapi, winsock, terminate

What can happen when I use [TerminateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) while Winsock [connect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms737625%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function is in progress?
I need to immediately shutdown the thread which is currently connecting to the socket but I don't know what can happen to the network adapter.

The [connect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms737625%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function has unfortunately no timeout parameter and the default system timeout value is too high. So is there any risk to interrupt this API function?

I've used Delphi tag just because I'm writing my application in Delphi, but it's much more Winsock and Windows API question.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to abort a `connect()` call is to close the socket from another thread context.  Otherwise, use `ConnectEx()` with overlapped I/O, like Martin said.

Comment: Thank you so much; this is exactly what I was looking for (even if the question was slightly differently phrased). Really the [connect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms737625%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) progress can be interrupted by calling [closesocket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms737582%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function from another thread context. This deserves many upvotes and from my side also the acception. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

By calling TerminateThread you create huge memory and resource leak. It may be OK if you do this just before your program exits (though it is not nice anyway...). But if you do this several times during program execution, your program finally crashes - no memory. Network adapter and its driver will be OK, they are protected well from buggy user mode programs.

Answer (score 0):

Use ConnectEx() in an overlapped call?  You could either use an event object, (a TEvent, say), in hEvent and wait on both that and some terminator event with WaitForMultipleObjects() or use a completion routine and wait on the terminator with WaitForSingleObjectEx() in a loop,that ignores WSA_OUTPUT_PENDING and IO_COMPLETION as results.

I guess it would be easier in this case to just wait with WaitForMultipleObjects().

Rgds,
Martin